# How to use virtual hosts with Iris?

Tags: go, go-iris

I'm wondering why the following won't work with Iris (v6.2.0):

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6"
    "gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6/adaptors/httprouter"
)

func main() {
    app := iris.New()
    app.Adapt(iris.DevLogger())
    app.Adapt(httprouter.New())

    exampleCom := app.Party("example.com")
    {
        exampleCom.Get("/", func(c *iris.Context) {
            c.Writef("hello from example.com")
        })
    }

    app.Get("/", func(c *iris.Context) {
        c.Writef("hello from everywhere else")
    })

    app.Listen(":3000")
}
```

I have pointed example.com to localhost in my hosts configuration. Visiting `localhost:3000` does give me "hello from everywhere else", but visiting `example.com:3000` gives me Iris' 404 page.

Comment: Just for consideration: [this post](http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html)

Comment: @Havelock oh damn, that's super sketchy, had no idea! will definitely start looking into alternatives.

Comment: Don''t believe those things, you can just go to the repository, Iris has unique features and  you can use tools which you can verify it by yourself, that post is under investigation by the Go Conduct team, don't believe dlsniper he wants to be famous by other's fame.